# ?. operator in C# not compiling for unknown reason

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

In the following code, one of the two variants does not compile:

```
class C
{
    public decimal DecimalField;
}

static C GetC() { return new C(); } //Can return null in reality.

C c = GetC(); //Get a C value from somewhere, this might be null

string toString1 = c?.DecimalField?.ToString(); //Does not compile.
string toString2 = (c?.DecimalField)?.ToString(); //Compiles.
```

> Error CS0023: Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'decimal'

Why does the simple form not compile?

Wouldn't the expression `c?.DecimalField` be of type `decimal?`? That value can be null so the `?.` operator should apply. I'm quite sure this is so because in this code:

```
var decimalValue = c?.DecimalField;
```

the `var` does resolve to `decimal?` according to the IDE.

Comment: Because `decimal` is not nullable

Comment: I think the decimal type cannot be null, so the null-coalesce operator makes no sense here.

Comment: its not `the simple form`, adding the parenthesis changes the expression

Comment: The obvious reason why parentheses could change an expression such as this (with two identical operators) is if the operator is right-associative. Unfortunately, there's no official spec that includes `?.` and (to my mind) it's difficult to know what associativity would even mean here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's a good point. I always was unclear about associativity with this operator as well. Clearly, the chain must *execute* left-to right but the types somehow seem to be right-to-left?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the null-conditional access operator is "short-circuiting". That is, if you write `a?.b.c` and execute it with `a` being `null`, then not only is `.b` not executed, but `.c` is also not executed.

As a consequence, when you write `a?.b?.c`, then the second null-conditional access operator is not about checking whether `a` or `a.b` is `null`. It's *only* about checking whether `a.b` is `null`. So, if `a.b` can never be `null`, like in your case, it doesn't make sense to use the null-conditional access operator, which is why the language does not allow it.

This also explains why `a?.b?.c` and `(a?.b)?.c` are not the same thing.

For more information about this, you can read [the C# Language Design Meeting notes where this was decided](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2014/LDM-2014-04-21.md#null-propagating-operator-associativity).

Comment: Spec draft: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#null-conditional-operator

Answer (score 2):

The type `decimal` is not a nullable type. Therefore your first expression does not compile. The difference to the second statement is that the inner part of the parenthesis could already be `null` if `c` was `null`. Therefore it compiles.

This could result in a `null` value: `(c?.DecimalField)`

The resulting type is `System.Nullable<decimal>` or short written `decimal?`

Comment: Why do parentheses change the type of the expression at all? That seems unusual.

Comment: It makes perfect sense in this case. If `c` would be null, the type of the expression needs to be a nullable type. But decimal (the type of `DecimalField`) is not nullable. This means, that the resulting type can't be decimal

Comment: `c?.DecimalField` is of type `decimal?`. The field does should not matter, the C# language rarely cares about where a value came from. It cares about the type. Here, the type *should* support ?.. What do you think about that?

Comment: @boot4life _"Why do parentheses change the type of the expression at all? That seems unusual."_ That is a very important thing you are about to understand. What you really want looks like this: `c?.DecimalField.ToString()` When you see it the first time, you may think that it is the same as `(c?.DecimalField).ToString()` __but this is not the case__. Suppose `c` is `null`. The latter will then call `ToString` on another `null`, which gives `""` in this case. The former will not call any `ToString` at all, and simply substitute `default(string)` which is null of type string.

Comment: @boot4life I don't know, what type of answer you are expecting. But what I told you is what happens in the C# language. What we think about it doesn't matter

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen OK, so the whole chain is short-circuited. This is what I was missing. I also now found a draft of the spec which confirms this (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#null-conditional-operator).

Comment: @boot4life Exactly. Good explanation. This also confused me when the `?.` operator was new (to me). When everything is reference types, the difference becomes more obvious, perhaps. Suppose `person`, `CurrentAddress` and `StreetName` are all reference types. Then `person?.CurrentAddress.StreetName` is meaningful, and short-circuits "all the way" if `person` is `null`. But `(person?.CurrentAddress).StreetName` is meaningless (yet allowed), since at first you take care if `person` is `null` (the `?.`), but then you "dot" on onto a null reference and get the `NulReferenceException` anyway.

Comment: (continued) And then `person?.CurrentAddress?.StreetName` is a third thing, also allowed, and can be meaningful as well if you anticipate that even in the case where `person` is non-null, the current address of that person could be missing (`null`), and therefore you have two cases of short-circuiting in one expression. You could check each case to convince yourself that these three (A `person?.CurrentAddress.StreetName`, B `(person?.CurrentAddress).StreetName`, C `person?.CurrentAddress?.StreetName`) are all different.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal type cannot be null, so the null-coalesce operator makes no sense here. Just set toString1 to some value.

In case you would like to compile it in all cases, you should edit your `DecimalField` which you are comparing to a nullable type by adding `decimal ?` insted of `decimal` on your field definition.

Answer (score 0):

You have three variants.

You can set default value, it returns `DecimalField` or `"0"`:

```
string toString = c?.DecimalField.ToString() ?? decimal.Zero.ToString();
```

Without default value, it returns `DecimalField` or `null`:

```
string toString = c?.DecimalField.ToString();
```

Or you can make `DecimalField` nullable, it returns `DecimalField` or `null`:

```
public decimal? DecimalField;
...
string toString1 = c?.DecimalField?.ToString(); //Compile now!
```